# EmailConfirmationListener in FOSUserBundle not redirecting to fos_user_registration_check_email

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, event-listener

In this doc it says to (from what I can tell) change the `getSubscribedEvents()` method to have a lower priority of -10. After enabling email confirmation in `config.yml` the email is sent and as far as that's concerned it works, but it won't redirect to the `/register/check-email` page. The listener for password resetting redirects to the correct page but this does not.

```
Registration success listener with enabled confirmation at the same time
------------------------------------------------------------------------

When you have registration confirmation and you want to hook up to
``FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS`` event you will have to prioritize this listener to be called
before ``FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\EmailConfirmationListener::onRegistrationSuccess``::

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => [
                ['onRegistrationSuccess', -10],
            ],
        ];
    }

If you don't do it, ``EmailConfirmationListener`` will be called earlier and you will be redirected to
``fos_user_registration_check_email`` route.
```

It might be referring to the priority of other listeners but I'm not sure. I assumed they meant to change the priority in `emailConfirmationListener.php`. Looking at `_profiler`, `/register/check-email` isn't requested at any time. Instead it redirects to `account/listings` which then redirects to the login page.

**EmailConfirmationListener.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Util\TokenGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class EmailConfirmationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $mailer;
    private $tokenGenerator;
    private $router;
    private $session;

    /**
     * EmailConfirmationListener constructor.
     *
     * @param MailerInterface         $mailer
     * @param TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator
     * @param UrlGeneratorInterface   $router
     * @param SessionInterface        $session
     */
    public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer, TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator, UrlGeneratorInterface $router, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->tokenGenerator = $tokenGenerator;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // return array(
        //     FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        // );

        return [
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => [
                ['onRegistrationSuccess', -10],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var $user \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface */
        $user = $event->getForm()->getData();

        $user->setEnabled(false);
        if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
            $user->setConfirmationToken($this->tokenGenerator->generateToken());
        }

        $this->mailer->sendConfirmationEmailMessage($user);

        $this->session->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());

        $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

**RegistrationController.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

/**
 * Controller managing the registration.
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    private $eventDispatcher;
    private $formFactory;
    private $userManager;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $this->formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

            if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user to check their email provider.
     */
    public function checkEmailAction(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->getSession()->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');

        if (empty($email)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_register'));
        }

        $request->getSession()->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (null === $user) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_security_login'));
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/check_email.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string  $token
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
    {
        $userManager = $this->userManager;

        $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
        }

        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user his account is now confirmed.
     */
    public function confirmedAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/confirmed.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'targetUrl' => $this->getTargetUrlFromSession($request->getSession()),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    private function getTargetUrlFromSession(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $key = sprintf('_security.%s.target_path', $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getProviderKey());

        if ($session->has($key)) {
            return $session->get($key);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was something in the theme itself, not FOS UserBundle. I just had to change a line in a function `onUserCreated()`

```
public function onUserCreated(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getUser();

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('['.$this->container->getParameter('app.project_name').'] New User Registration')
        ->setFrom($this->container->getParameter('app.email_from'))
        ->setTo($user->getEmail())
        ->setBody($this->container->get('templating')->render('AppBundle::Email/user_registered.html.twig', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]), 'text/html');

    $this->container->get('mailer')->send($message);

    $response = $event->getResponse();
    // $response->setTargetUrl($this->container->get('router')->generate('listing_my')); this line
    $response->setTargetUrl($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_registration_check_email'));
}
```